# Как найти длину отрезка зная координаты точек?

Tags: c#, математика

В колледже задали для изучения С# написать прогу для нахождения длины отрезка.
Но почему-то код жалуется на int xone = int.Parse(onex);
Подскажите что со мной не так? (если будет возможно, можете объяснить точнее что с кодом не так?)

Само задание:
Ввести с клавиатуры координаты двух точек (A и B) на плоскости
(вещественные числа). 
Вычислить длину отрезка AB. 
Пример:
Введите координаты точки A:
5.5 3.5
Введите координаты точки B:
1.5 2
Длина отрезка AB = 4.272

```
       private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string onex = textBox4.Text; //беру значение Х первой точки
            string oney = textBox5.Text; //беру значение У первой точки
            string twox = textBox6.Text; //беру значение Х второй точки
            string twoy = textBox7.Text; //беру значение У второй точки

            int xone = int.Parse(onex); // честно, так и не понял для чего int.Parse нужен)
            int yone = int.Parse(oney);
            int xtwo = int.Parse(twox);
            int ytwo = int.Parse(twoy);

            int j = (xtwo*xtwo) - 2*xtwo*xone + (xone*xone); // x(2)^2 - 2x(2)y(2) + y(2)^2
            int k = (ytwo*ytwo) - 2*ytwo*yone + (yone*yone); // x(1)^2 - 2x(1)y(1) + y(1)^2
            int l = (j+k); // складываем что получилось
            double r = Math.Sqrt(l); // находим квадратный корень

            label8.Text = "Длина отрезка равна: " + r.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки.

Comment: System.FormatException: "Входная строка имела неверный формат."

На строчке int xone = int.Parse(onex);

Comment: Внесите эту информацию в вопрос.

Comment: А зачем вы разложили возведение в квадрат? `Math.pow(xtwo - xone, 2)` короче и понятнее…

Comment: вещественное число и ``int`` это две разные разницы

Answer (score 4):

Если вы вводите вещественное число, то и преобразовывайте строку в вещественное (`float` или `double`)

```
float xone = float.Parse(onex);
```

и т.д.

Сейчас же вы пытаетесь строку с точкой преобразовать в **целое** (`int`) число, поэтому и возникает ошибка.

Чтобы понять, для чего нужен `int.Parse` или  `float.Pars` - посмотрите [хелп](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.parse?view=net-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_Single_Parse_System_String_)

Comment: @BestOsuplayer  Ознакомьтесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer